# How to send form data containing checkboxes to spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is the form to help understand it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtiKc.png

The html page with that form has its model data populated with the  controller method below.So each checkbox refers to a Music or Advertisement object placed in the model.How can I send the objects of the selected check boxes to a spring controller?Html is below also

```
@Autowired
AdvertisementService advertisementService;
@Autowired
MusicService musicService;
@RequestMapping("/web/createSchedule")
public String createSchedule(Model model) {
    //display the create schedule page
    //get logged in user
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    //add advertisements to model
    List<Advertisement> advertisements =advertisementService.findByUserGroup_IdOrderByDateAddedDesc(user.getUserGroup().getId());
    model.addAttribute("advertisements",advertisements);
    List<Music> musics = musicService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("musics",musics);
    return "createschedule";
}
```

Html

```
<form th:action="@{/web/createschedule}" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputDescription">Enter the description of the schedule(eg week schedule 10/03/18--17/03/18)</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" name = "inputDescription" id="inputDescription" placeholder="description"></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm" style=" height: 200px; width: 600px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <h3>Pick the advertisements you want this schedule to have</h3>
                <div  th:each="advertisement : ${advertisements}">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1"/>
                        <label th:text="${advertisement.description + ' Added:' +advertisement.dateAdded} " class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm" style=" height: 200px; width: 600px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <h3>Pick the music you want this schedule to have</h3>
                <div  th:each="music : ${musics}">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck2"/>
                        <label th:text="${music.description} " class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<p>You select when you want your advertisements to play in the next step</p>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create schedule</button>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider few things to achieve this.

On your form, include `th:object` and once you submit your form it will return `yourObject` to controller.

```
<form th:action="@{/web/createschedule}"  th:object="${yourObject}" method="post">
```

You need to include `th:field` for checkbox

```
 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="this_value_will_map_to_your_modal_Object" id="defaultCheck1"/>
```

Now on your controller, you need `@ModelAttribute` annotatation that will map `yourObject` to `YourModel` Object.

```
public String createSchedule(@ModelAttribute YourModel model)
```

Make sure `YourModel` class is defined with appropriate parameters.

```
public class YourModel{
  private List<String> checkedItems;
 //other parameters as needed

 //getters setters

}
```

Comment: thanks man,what will the string contain in my case?Can I map the checkbox in a way that the model class contains an arraylist of Music and Advertisement and pass those from the checkbox?

Comment: In your case list contains all the value of your checkbox you specify using th:value.